# Add attributes to js media fields in django's widgets

Tags: django, attributes, requirejs, django-widget

I am using AMD loading with requirejs for most of my javascript but I have trouble using them in django's widgets.

Django's documentation states that a media should be embedded in the following way:

```
class Media:
    js = ('animations.js')
```

This creates the following html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.example.com/animations.js"></script>
```

But what if I want to have this?

```
<script data-main="scripts/animations" src="scripts/require.js"></script>
```

How do I tell django to insert the *data-main* attribute?

Thank you for your answers.